# what is the maximum number of patches

Tags: netlogo

I am messing about with GIS and what not. So I want to have as many patches as I can alas when I go too large 3600 x 1800 I end up with a crash and a verbose error starting with A InvocationTargetException.

Is it system based or in the network code?

How big can I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the NetLogo FAQ at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig :

> The NetLogo engine has no fixed limits on size [...]

In practice, the main limit is memory. Are you sure you need that high of patch resolution?

In cases where your model has turtles sampling raster data, you can use high resolution GIS raster datasets while keeping patch resolution low and then have turtles sample the dataset on the fly instead of importing into patch variables. Look closely at how the GIS Gradient Example is written in ModelLibrary/ CodeExamples/ GIS.